# How to check if a username exists in a text file via File/FileWriter/Scanner classes

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because after running the program in my main class, it completely skips over the

```
while(usernameCheck.hasNext()){
    //code...
}
```

loop even though I purposely put a username that's already in my "accounts.txt" file. I also tried the `contains()` method but obviously if I put lets say "John1" and "John" is already in my accounts.txt file, it won't accept it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class CreateAccount {

public static void newAccount() throws IOException{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("accounts.txt",true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


    System.out.println("Please enter a username: ");
    String user = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file = new File("accounts.txt");
    Scanner usernameCheck = new Scanner(file);

    while(usernameCheck.hasNext()){
        String existingUsername = usernameCheck.nextLine();

        if(user.equalsIgnoreCase(existingUsername)){

            System.out.println("Username already exists");
            System.out.println("Please enter a username: ");
            user = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a password: ");
    String pass = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Account created!");
```

*** After reading my code I realize I also have another problem: Even if I do create a username that doesn't exist in my "accounts.txt" class, it'll keep repeating the prompt that a username already exists because of the hasNext() method. What can I do about this?

Comment: What IDE are you using to write your code? Does it have a debugger? If so, step through the code and see what it's doing.

Comment: @Ken White I'm using Eclipse

Comment: Then it has a debugger, right? Have you thought about what problems opening a `FileWriter` and a `Scanner` on the same file at the same time might cause?

Comment: Do you have any extra spaces in your file, or does each user name come right up to the end of the line?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I do not; each username comes right up to the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

I threw this in and tested it. It finds a name for me. What I would guess is happening is your file path is not true.

```
 File file = new File("accounts.txt");
```

Start by finding the full path of this text file. put the full path in, and then see how you can make the path more relative.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see what my problem is now, the code is creating the "accounts.txt" file in my src folder AND my package folder. Do you happen to know what could be causing this?

Comment: Regarding your comment in your previous answer: what else could I do? The question was obvious low quality, and your answer offered no explanation whatsoever, it was just a code dump. There are times when I've seen great answers to terrible questions, and those I up-vote, but those answers focus on offering a great explanation of both the original poster's problems and how to solve them, *in a general sense*, so that the answer is helpful not just to the original poster (the OP) but to all future visitors to this site. Yours was little more than a code dump answer and so any way ...

Comment: ... that you look at it was low quality.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between the code shown below and your code is quite evident. The prompts to the User are enclosed within **while** loop blocks for at least two reasons:

- If the User enters a User Name that is already contained within the ***accounts.txt*** file then the User can be informed of such and be given the opportunity to enter another User Name. The same applies to the Password prompt. If an invalid Password is provided (like nothing) then the User is informed and given the opportunity to enter a valid Password.
- To ensure the User actually enters a User Name or a Password.

These of course have nothing to do with file writing but does enhance options to the User so as to ensure there is actually something to write to file.

To read the **accounts.txt** file, the **Scanner.hasNextLine()** method is used instead of the **Scanner.hasNext()** method and here is why:

The *Scanner.hasNext()* method is written to work with the *Scanner.next()* method and the *Scanner.hasNextLine()* method is written to work with the *Scanner.nextLine()* method.

The **Scanner.next()** method works with whatever delimiter is used as your token separator. By default Scanner uses whitespace as a token separator, so, if reading for a User Name which could have a First and Last name separated by a whitespace this would provide 2 tokens (First Name and Last Name) which means you would need to make 2 calls to the *Scanner.next()* method to get the full User Name (one for each word). Think what is required now if there is a blank line in file or a space in front of the User Name in file.

The *Scanner.nextLine()* method however reads a complete file line of text, so it would read the User Name from file all in one call. You will also notice that I've also applied the **String.trim()** method to the end of the *Scanner.nextLine()* method:

`String existingUsername = usernameCheck.nextLine().trim();`

This is done so as to remove any leading or trailing tabs or white-spaces from the file line should there be any. We can do this since the *Scanner.nextLine()* method returns a String. Oh...Using the Scanner.hasNext() method could be why your loop is getting skipped over.

A mechanism has also been placed in code to allow the User to exit the **newAccount()** method at the **"Enter User Name"** prompt. If the letter **q** is supplied at this prompt then the the method is exited with a **return;** statement.

As mentioned earlier, the Password prompt has also been placed within a **while** loop so that validation of sorts can be done. Currently only a check that the Password actually contains something is done, this can however be expanded to cover whatever Password type validation you like. Perhaps a Password of a specific length, containing specific character types, etc.

Here is the code:

```
public static void newAccount() throws IOException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file = new File("accounts.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
    Scanner usernameCheck = new Scanner(file);
    String user = "";
    while (user.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a User name (q to exit): ");
        user = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
        if (user.toLowerCase().equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("User Exit!");
            return;  // exit the method.
        }
        while (usernameCheck.hasNextLine()) {
            String existingUsername = usernameCheck.nextLine().trim();
            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(existingUsername)) {
                System.err.println("Username already exists! Try Again.\n");
                user = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    usernameCheck.close(); // Close the Scanner file object
    String pass = "";
    while (pass.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a password for " + user + ": ");
        pass = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (pass.equals("")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Password! Try Again.\n");
        }
    }

    fw.write(user + System.lineSeparator());
    fw.write(pass + System.lineSeparator());
    fw.close(); // close the FileWriter object.

    System.out.println("Account created!");
}
```

Comment: could I ask what the difference was between what I was doing and what you did? I just wanna know for future reference when it comes to File writing and such